# How can fix "it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'" when I use datalist?

Tags: html, content-security-policy, datalist, unsafe-inline

When I use datalist with the Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'", it gives error, "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-pIL...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.".

The data list works as I hope in the browser, however the error message is annoying.
As I hope to keep the security as strong as possible, I do not want to change Content-Security-Policy to unsafe-inline. Could you give me a hint to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
</head>
<body>
   <label for="animalList" class="form-label">animal</label>
   <input class="form-control" list="animalOptions" id="animalList" placeholder="">
   <datalist id="animalOptions">
     <option value="dog">
     <option value="cat">
   </datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This error is triggered when there's an inline style (ie `style=""`) somewhere in your markup, can you check if that's the issue?

Comment: The code shown here is all I have. I think you can reproduce the error with this code.

Comment: Wow that's really strange. I suppose it's actually a bug in Chrome, because the issue doesn't occur in Firefox.

Comment: I can reproduce the error using chrome and edge. Thank you for that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of this error just add into your CSP:

`style-src-attr 'sha256-pILX+5FGCpLRHvNBgtABIdSMmytrYudGxJBUYXY1t0s=' 'unsafe-hashes';`

This directive works in browsers on Chromium engine only and applies to *style=* attribute. Other browsers will follow `style-src` rules. For `<style>...</style>` blocks a Chrome will follow `style-src` rules too.

Comment: It works! Thank you.  But 'unsafe-hashes' relaxes the security policy some extent. I wish there was the more robust way.

Comment: Any source you add to the policy relax it in some way. `'unsafe-hashes'` allows only `style=` with the specified hashes, nothing else.

Comment: hash values suppose to be auto generated. You have put it static which makes CSP unsecure.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a new bug in chromium based browsers (including Edge). It doesn't appear in Firefox v89.

Comment: I think so. I still need some workarounds. Do you know how to avoid this error and get the same result?

Comment: The 'unsafe-hashes' workaround by granty will work, but is likely to be identified as insecure if that style-src rule catches on. The datalist functions without any noticeable deterioration despite the browser error, so I have left it for the moment. The chromium team is aware of the issue (even though they may not address it for a long time/ever): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1216456&q=csp%20error%20datalist&can=2

Comment: As you mentioned, ignoring the error can be a compromise solution for the time being.